# How to show something result for lots of time in two for loop?

Tags: matlab

I use matlab to write a code which  can show some calculated result for two times,i mean,if `A=[1 2 3]`,`B=[1 2 3]`,and I want to calculate the addition of each elements in the `A` and `B` vector for two times

I mean

first result should be `A(1)+B(1) A(1)+B(1) A(1)+B(1) = 2 2 2`

Second result should be `A(1)+B(2) A(1)+B(2) A(1)+B(2) = 3 3 3`

Third result should be `A(1)+B(3)  A(1)+B(3)  A(1)+B(3) = 4 4 4`

Fourth result should be `A(2)+B(1) A(2)+B(1) A(2)+B(1) = 3 3 3`  And so on

The final result ,a, should be `[2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6 ]` or

```
2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4

3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5

4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6
```

I have written the code here,but the result is not what i wanted,the window showed me

```
A=[1 2 3]
B=[1 2 3]
for i=1:3
    for j=1:3
        for k=1:3
            a(i,j)=A(i)+B(j) 
        end
    end
end
```

```
a =

   2     3     4
   3     4     5
   4     5     6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to take `k` into account when you choose the indices for `a`, so that it goes from 1 to 9 in each row

```
A=[1 2 3];
B=[1 2 3];

for i=1:3
    for j=1:3
        for k=1:3
            a(i,(3*(j-1))+k)=A(i)+B(j) 
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can write the whole thing much simpler with one or zero loops:

```matlab
A = [10,20,30];
B = [1,2,3];
repetition_count = 3;


disp('first option');
C = A + B.';
for x = C(:);
	disp(repmat(x,[1,repetition_count]));
end

disp('second option');
disp(C(:) * ones(1,repetition_count));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1BCsIwEEXX5hSza6pBYrszdNH2GFKkJClkYSY0UXr7OA0Iosv/3583qNP8sjn30MHtIkUjRSsnxYaSRSNaCqsNNrnk0N81Pn0i1irGmHEx8Gpxa0yAYedVrdhIuIcTDOdKsQVX2KgY@ZXQoVyQ7jEnvgl68KueappZbz7yaDV682Uv9W6DI6C3kf87SJHzGw)

Answer (score 2):

Using [implicit expansion](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2016/10/24/matlab-arithmetic-expands-in-r2016b/) (r2016b and above) and [`kron`](https://ch.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/kron.html), the kronecker product:

```
%Example 1D array
A=[1 2 3];
B=[1 2 3];

%get the result
res = kron(A+B.',ones(size(A)))
```

Which give:

```
res =

   2   2   2   3   3   3   4   4   4
   3   3   3   4   4   4   5   5   5
   4   4   4   5   5   5   6   6   6
```